# Replace multiple commas with a single one - linux command

Tags: linux, replace, sed, command-line-interface

This is an output from my google csv contacts (which contains more than 1000 contacts):

```
A-Tech Computers Hardware,A-Tech Computers,,Hardware,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Low,,,* My Contacts,,,,,,,,,Home,+38733236313,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I need a linux cli command to replace the duplicate commas, with single commas, so i get this:

```
A-Tech Computers Hardware,A-Tech Computers,Hardware,Low,* My Contacts,Home,+38733236313,
```

What I usually do in notepad++ is Replace ",," with "," six times.

I tried with:

```
cat googlecontacts.txt | sed -e 's/,,/,/g' -e 's/,,/,/g' -e 's/,,/,/g'  -e 's/,,/,/g' -e 's/,,/,/g' -e 's/,,/,/g' > google.txt
```

But it doesn't work...
However, when I try it on smaller files (two lines) it works... :(

Help please!

Comment: Be careful as you may screw up your (currently) well-formed CSV data. If one of your contacts has extra (or less) information than the others, you may end up with a file which you cannot open as CSV file anymore. Perhaps you should manipulate the data as CSV (use R, Python or whatever language you feel comfortable with, including Awk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your line still compliant after modification(not the concern of the question)

```
sed 's/,\{2,\}/,/g' googlecontacts.txt > google.txt
```

- It replace any occurence greater than 1 of `,` by a single `,` any place on the line
- any space between `,` is consider as a correct field, so not modified

In your command, you need to recursive change the character and not reexecute several time the same (there is always a gretear occurence possible) `,` like this

```
cat googlecontacts.txt | sed ':a
# make your change
s/,,/,/g
# if change occur, retry once again by returning to line :a
t a' > google.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You need the `squeeze` option of `tr`:

```
tr -s ',' < yourFile
```

You can see it in action like this:

```
echo hello,,there,,,,I,have,,too,many,,,commas | tr -s ,
hello,there,I,have,too,many,commas
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/,,*/,/g' file
```

or

```
sed 's/,\+/,/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @potong, your solution worked for one of my requirement. I had to replace the | symbol in the first line of my file and used this solution with small change.

```
sed -i "1s/|'*//g" ${filename}
```

I was unable to add comments so thought of posting it as an answer. Please excuse